# Remove Box Drive from Navigation Pane on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

How can I remove the Box Drive from the navigation pane on windows 10? I removed dropbox by changing attributes in regedit. It would be great if someone could tell me which attributes I should change to remove the Box Drive from the navigation pane.

Here is an example for removing Dropbox from the navigation pane:

Hit "Windows-Key + R", type "regedit" and then "OK".

Go to the paths

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A}\ShellFolder

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A}\ShellFolder

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A}\ShellFolder

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A}\ShellFolder

Double click on "Attributes"

Change the value from f080004d to f090004d

Open Task Manager and kill every "explorer.exe"-process under "Details"

Restart "explorer.exe" with "File -> New Task"

Comment: Can you just uninstall it? What happens when you do that? What is the "navigation pane"? And what research have you done regarding this? Does Box provide manual uninstall documentation?

Comment: I want to use but have a short cut in the navigation pane. Navigation pane is the left pane in explorer where you see for instance "This PC" or "Network". I removed Dropbox from the navigation pane by following these steps. I was hoping something similar is possible for Box Drive.